# TopicsNotExistError: The topic(s) xxx do not exist in kafka-node?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

i am using kafka to build two consumer client as the code shown below, but it gave me a error, saying

```
TopicsNotExistError: The topic(s) DEVICE_BINDED do not exist
    at new TopicsNotExistError (/Users/xisizhe/Documents/projects/mean-master/node_modules/_kafka-node@3.0.0@kafka-node/lib/errors/TopicsNotExistError.js:11:9)
    at /Users/xisizhe/Documents/projects/mean-master/node_modules/_kafka-node@3.0.0@kafka-node/lib/client.js:464:43
```

How can I solve it?

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');

function ConnectionProvider() {
    this.getConsumer = function (topic_name) {
          console.log('consumer consumer',topic_name);
          this.client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181");
          this.kafkaConsumerConnection = new kafka.Consumer(this.client,[ { topic: topic_name, partition: 0 }]);
          this.kafkaConsumerConnection.on('ready', function () {
            console.log('consumer ready!')
          })
      return this.kafkaConsumerConnection;
    };

    //Code will be executed when we start Producer
    this.getProducer = function () {

        if (!this.kafkaProducerConnection) {
            this.client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181");
            var HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
            //this.kafkaProducerConnection = new HighLevelProducer(this.client);
            this.kafkaProducerConnection = new kafka.Producer(this.client);
            var self = this;
            this.kafkaProducerConnection.on('ready', function () {
                logger.debug('producer ready');

                self.kafkaProducerConnection.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.error("Error " + err)
                })
            });

        }
        return this.kafkaProducerConnection;
    };
}


const device_add_consumer  = connection.getConsumer(config.kafka.topic.DEVICE_ADDED);

const device_binded_consumer  = connection.getConsumer(config.kafka.topic.DEVICE_BINDED);
```

Comment: Well, can you show the command that describes the topic? Did you create the topic yet?

Comment: And you might want to refer to the documentation... *zookeeper based client has been deprecated and is likely to be removed in the future. Please use the KafkaClient instead* https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/blob/master/README.md#example

Comment: do I have to explicitly create the topic for the client, I assume it can create the topic through this code automatically new kafka.Consumer(this.client,[ { topic: topic_name, partition: 0 }]);

Comment: you have to explicitly create a topic through code or command line.Though i am not familiar with node, but I think something like : https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#createtopicstopics-cb

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to explicitly create the topic for the client

Yes, you should. Otherwise you get whatever defaults that are set by the broker (which if you're only using localhost, you've probably not tuned)

> I assume it can create the topic through this code automatically

That's not a safe assumption. The Kafka server properties define if topics are automatically created, and that could be disabled.

You need to manually create it, either via Node or using `kafka-topics --create` CLI tool from your Kafka installation